# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime

I am trying to insert date in my database table through a textbox. But even if I am converting the string into Datetime I am still getting this error :

> "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value".

I have taken datetime datatype in my database. This is my code :

```
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO tblProject(project_starting_date,project_ending_date)values(@projectstartingdate,@projectendendingdate)", objconn);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectstartingdate", DateTime.Parse(txtStartingdate.Text).ToString());
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectendendingdate", DateTime.Parse(txtProjectendingdate.Text).ToString());
    DateTime stdate;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(txtStartingdate.Text, out stdate))
    {
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectstartingdate",stdate);
        SqlParameter projstrtdate = new SqlParameter("@projectstartingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        projstrtdate.Value = stdate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(projstrtdate);
    }
    DateTime enddate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtProjectendingdate.Text, out enddate))
    {
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectendendingdate", enddate);
        SqlParameter projenddate = new SqlParameter("@projectendendingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        projenddate.Value = enddate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(projenddate);
    }
    if (objconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        objconn.Open();
    }
    norowaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    objconn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write( ex.ToString());
}
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the types associated with your columns? The error seems to suggest they are `nvarchar` columns.. not `datetime` as you were expecting. Show us the definition of your table.

Comment: @Simon: My database fields are-
project_starting_date(datetime,null)
project_ending_date(datetime,null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your locale configuration is trying to convert the data string in a wrong unexpected format.

Try with the following:

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtStartingdate.Text, out stdate)
{
    SqlParameter projectStartingDateParam = new SqlParameter("@projectstartingdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        projectStartingDateParam.Value = stdate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(projectStartingDateParam);
}
```

Do the same with "projectendingdate". Create a SqlParameter with SqlDbType equals to SqlDbType.DateTime and add it to the query command (cmd variable).

If this dosen't work, double check your table structure if it's in DateTime format. 
Do a manually insert directly in database via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes I have taken data type as datetime in my sql server.

Comment: With the code of the answer did not work as well? Or you have not had time to test?

Comment: After doing the same as suggested by you, I am still getting the same problem. Please suggest me some other alternative. I have also entered the data manually into my database table and after inserting I again tried to insert through code. But the problem still exist.

Comment: Please check the code in my question I have updated my question.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply friend. I have updated the code I posted in my question as suggested by you. Please check.
And please guide me If I need to make any changes in my code.

Comment: Debug stdate and enddate, they are in the correct format ?

Comment: Instead of using the variable stdate, date it manually for testing. 
`projstrtdate.Value = DateTime.Today; `
`projenddate.Value = DateTime.Now; `

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. I fixed it by deleting the corresponding columns in the data base and recreate it with the correct format "so date time for you". problem was fixed.
it seems there is still information in the data base telling what format it was before.

Comment: I even tried by truncating my table and then again inserting the value. But it still reflects the same error.